# image pixel reading in big_endian and little_endian

Tags: c++, image

I am now reading the sourse code of Leptonica, which is a good image processing library. In this library it provides a function to set pixels value when the pixel's depth is 8 (corresponding to grey-scale image):

```
/*!
 *  l_setDataByte()
 *
 *      Input:  line  (ptr to beginning of data line)
 *              n     (pixel index)
 *              val   (val to be inserted: 0 - 0xff)
 *      Return: void
 */
void
l_setDataByte(void    *line,
              l_int32  n,
              l_int32  val)
{
#ifdef  L_BIG_ENDIAN
    *((l_uint8 *)line + n) = val;
#else  /* L_LITTLE_ENDIAN */
    *(l_uint8 *)((l_uintptr_t)((l_uint8 *)line + n) ^ 3) = val;
#endif  /* L_BIG_ENDIAN */
}

typedef   unsigned int   uintptr_t;
typedef unsigned char           l_uint8;
```

For the case of big endian it is the code is very easy to understand, but for the little endian case it is very hard to understand. Could some explain why pixel value is set in this way when the computer is little endian? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question or not, but some image formats allow for both number formatting. For example, in TIFF images, there is a flag at the very beginning of the file that says if the numbers are written in big or little endian format (I think it is Intel or Motorolla format in the TIFF language, so the flag is either `II` or `MM`).

Comment: The underlying pixel data storage is an array of 32-bit values.  It is setting the 32-bit array element from an 8-bit value and does so with the equivalent of val << 24.  BigEndian requires setting the 1st byte, LittleEndian requires setting the last byte of the 32-bit value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endianness tends to be easier for computers to read in little-endian (less math in some cases) but easier for people to read in big-endian (since that's how we write math) and thus easier to debug raw data. As such, many things differ on which endianess to use and why.

Since images and other files transfer between computers, the computer's endian preference has to be ignored in favor of the one the file uses; this includes images as well as any other file types which aren't processor bound. Sometimes that's defined by format, sometimes individually (as per the comment about TIFF declarian endianess in the header).